How to build a truss that yields in-plane, but that resists torsion?
Consider the following truss, inspired by a bicycle frame.

For the purpose of this question, assume all joints are ball-jointed.
The rule in bicycle frame manufacturing is that it is desirable to have maximum torsional strength — to flex minimally when a rider uses their arms to counter-act the pressure on the bicycle cranks — but that the frame should also be sufficiently flexible to bend in-the-plane-of-the-frame — sparing the rider from feeling the vibrations on long bike ride.
These dual objectives meant that for the last two decades carbon fibres have been the material of choice for bicycle frames at all major races.
Pundits always point out that the dual objectives above can be achieved by a suitable layering of the carbon fibers. I'm having trouble understanding how this can be done, and am hoping a truss model would make it clearer.
Would, for example, using very rigid members for the violet lines (top and bottom; on both sides) while using much more modest members for the red lines achieve this dual objective? For our purposes here assume that the green members are infinitely strong.
Related
This question is a sequel.
